# Sometimes my laptop boots straight to BIOS

Tags: windows-10, boot, ssd, bios, asus-laptop

I have a ASUS TUF fx505-dt laptop running Windows 10 with an Intel SSD as the boot drive (and the only drive).

Sometimes when I boot my laptop, I am led straight to the BIOS where I see [this screen.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kCw6w.jpg) The drive is not detected as during a normal boot the BIOS looks like [this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oXXor.jpg) When I checked the drive health it is at 97% according to CrystalDiskInfo and everything seems fine. I have also run Intel's SSD Toolbox, no problems there too.

This thing happens randomly and has happened 3-4 times now. Initially I tried enabling/disabling Fast boot option in the BIOS. The firs two times it worked but not anymore. I kept force restarting the laptop through the power button and was eventually able to boot it. It's Asus laptop BIOS so most of the stuff is locked.

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/02SFk.png) is the SMART data of the SSD.

So what might be the problem here? Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: The disk might be failing. Post here its SMART data (if you don't have a disk utility for this, one such is [Speccy](https://www.ccleaner.com/speccy)).

Comment: @harrymc Speccy says S.M.A.R.T not support.

Comment: Try to find some information in the Event Viewer, as related to disk problems.

Comment: @harrymc I added the SMART data. I got it from PassMark's DiskCheckup

Comment: The disk seems OK. If the problem is in the motherboard then a repair shop could help.

Comment: @harrymc Thanks, I'll try to take it to a shop.